# Why doesn't my autostart file run a simple shell script

Tags: raspbian, boot, script, bash, lxde

I am trying to launch a simple script (let's say it is `/home/pi/python/python_code/hello-world.sh`) from the `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` file.

I have added the following line to the `autostart` file to do this:

```
@lxterminal -e "/home/pi/python/python_code/hello-world.sh"
```

The `hello-world.sh` script runs fine from the command line, but when I boot the Pi, autostart opens a terminal window with `hello-world"` (note the trailing double quotes) in the title bar and does nothing else.

Comment: Are you sure the two double quotes are the same? Word processors often automatically replace them with left / right quotation marks. You can try leaving them out completely because the script name doesn't contain spaces

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm using Idle (in Python 3 environment) as my IDE, and it appears to use basic double quotes (not "sixes and nines" as as common with beginning and ending quotes provided in most word processors). I have also tried replacing the double quotes with single quotes with similar results (i.e., terminal opens on boot showing hello-world' in title bar). Removing the quotes completely gives a different symptom - terminal window appears to open and immediately close upon boot.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could directly add your hello-world.sh to /etc/rc.local

For Example, try this

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Add your script to end of the file

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

bash /home/pi/python/python_code/hello-world.sh
```

To save and exit, type Ctrl-x, and then Y

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/).  We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

The `lxterminal -e "..."` is presenting an error when it is started in the `autostart` file. Example, with the `lxterminal -e "Hello World"` in the `autostart` file, the error will display `"Hello World"` in the title bar. Change that to `lxterminal -e "Hello/World"` and the error will be `World"`.

Without the quotes around the executable file, it should run fine. However, remember that the executable files in `autostart` file are forked to run in their own process and when they (`lxterminal -e ...`) end the process ends also.

If your program is a shell script, add `sleep 15` at the end (before the `exit` command if present) and the terminal will display the information for 15 seconds and then exit. For a Python script add `input()` to hold the terminal window open.